# How to add label via JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function that creates different radio buttons for each month of the day. I have added a label that has the default value 1 in each button. But now I have two problems.

1. I am not able to click on the buttons anylonger, which I could before. Before the label, I could click on the button and add value to my MySql db.
2. When I change the month, the new month shows up below to one on the top. So if im on february, I get 28 buttons, and when I change to march, I get 31 bottons below. Before the function just added the buttons, so it added 3 buttons when I changed the month.

To get the next month:

```
function next() {
  if (showDate.getMonth() == 11) {
    showDate.setMonth( 0 );
    showDate.setFullYear( showDate.getFullYear()+1 );
  } else {
    showDate.setMonth( showDate.getMonth()+1 );
  }
  document.getElementById("displayingMonth").innerHTML = months[showDate.getMonth()];
  drawTable( showDate );
}
```

To draw the table:

```
var showDate = new Date();
var months = ["Januari", "Februari", "March", "April", "May", "June",
              "July", "Augusti", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var weeks = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuseday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];

function drawTable(forDate) {
  var daysInMonth = new Date(forDate.getFullYear(),forDate.getMonth()+1,0).getDate();
  var v = c +1;        
  var cellsToDraw = daysInMonth;
  var month = forDate.getMonth()+1;// non-index version of selected Month
  var newdate = forDate.getFullYear() + "-" + month;
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  table.innerHTML = "";
  for (var r = 0; r < (daysInMonth / 7); r++) {
    var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
    table.appendChild(newRow);
    for (var c = 0; c < 31 && cellsToDraw > 0; c++) {
      var newCell = document.createElement("td");
      var input = document.createElement("input");
      var label = document.createElement("label");
      input.setAttribute("type", "radio");
      input.setAttribute("name", "day");
      label.appendChild(document.createTextNode("1"));
      newCell.appendChild(label);
      newRow.appendChild(newCell);
      cellsToDraw--;
    }
  }
}
```

Onload code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("displayingMonth").innerHTML = months[showDate.getMonth()];
    drawTable( showDate );
};
```

**HTML**:

```
 <table id="table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"   border-collapse="collapse";>
          <input id="newCell"type="hidden"name="day" value="">
  <h1 id="displayingMonth"></h1>
```

all help is appriciated! :)

Comment: Do you have any styling applied that you're not showing us? Secondly, as an aside, you may want to look into the default methods of a table object `insertCell` and `insertRow` they could save you some time and lines of code.

Comment: @zfrisch no im not using any css

Comment: Could you provide a working example? Your code isn't complete enough to run which makes it difficult to troubleshoot. My guess would be that you're not assigning the same name to the radio button as you are to the for attribute of the label, which means they aren't linked, and when you render them the label overlays the radio button, which effectively disables any clicking of the element.

Comment: @zfrisch added the last pice of code, not sure if it helps?

Comment: Not quite. :) You must be missing HTML. It's looking for something with the ID of displayingMonth and there isn't anything in your example code.

Comment: [Document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

Comment: @zfrisch I added the html for the displayingMonth!

Comment: @RonRoyston not quite sure what you mean?

Comment: @Alison I think my answer should help. I wasn't able to duplicate the issue with your months appearing below one another when calling `next`

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost you need an `id` to link a label and a radio button. I set this on the `input` and the `label` at the same time with the line `input.id = label.htmlFor = rando_id;`

`rando_id` is simply a randomly generated number up to 5000 prefixed with "radio_".

Lastly you didn't append the radio button to the screen at any point. I added it to the label element with `label.appendChild(input);`

```
  var rando_id = "radio_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(5000));
  var newCell = document.createElement("td");
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  var label = document.createElement("label");
  input.id = label.htmlFor = rando_id;
  input.setAttribute("type", "radio");
  input.setAttribute("name", "day");
  label.appendChild(document.createTextNode("1"));
  label.appendChild(input);
```

```js
function next() {
  if (showDate.getMonth() == 11) {
    showDate.setMonth( 0 );
    showDate.setFullYear( showDate.getFullYear()+1 );
  } else {
    showDate.setMonth( showDate.getMonth()+1 );
  }
  document.getElementById("displayingMonth").innerHTML = months[showDate.getMonth()];
  drawTable( showDate );
}


var showDate = new Date();
var months = ["Januari", "Februari", "March", "April", "May", "June",
              "July", "Augusti", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var weeks = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuseday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];

function drawTable(forDate) {
  var daysInMonth = new Date(forDate.getFullYear(),forDate.getMonth()+1,0).getDate();
  var v = c +1;        
  var cellsToDraw = daysInMonth;
  var month = forDate.getMonth()+1;// non-index version of selected Month
  var newdate = forDate.getFullYear() + "-" + month;
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  table.innerHTML = "";
  for (var r = 0; r < (daysInMonth / 7); r++) {
    var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
    table.appendChild(newRow);
    for (var c = 0; c < 31 && cellsToDraw > 0; c++) {
      var rando_id = "radio_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(5000));
      var newCell = document.createElement("td");
      var input = document.createElement("input");
      var label = document.createElement("label");
      input.id = label.htmlFor = rando_id;
      input.setAttribute("type", "radio");
      input.setAttribute("name", "day");
      label.appendChild(document.createTextNode("1"));
      label.appendChild(input);
      newCell.appendChild(label);
      newRow.appendChild(newCell);
      cellsToDraw--;
    }
  }
}



    document.getElementById("displayingMonth").innerHTML = months[showDate.getMonth()];
    drawTable( showDate );
```

```html
<table id="table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"   border-collapse="collapse";>
          <input id="newCell"type="hidden"name="day" value="">
  <h1 id="displayingMonth"></h1>
```

Comment: thanks! but I want number 1 to be inside of the button. I have made my buttons a bit larger

Comment: @Alison What do you mean by "inside of the button"?

Comment: So the inputs width and height  has been changed. So the numer 1 on top of the button.

Comment: @Alison I mean... you can do that in styling, but if you're going to do that why wouldn't you just use an actual button instead of a radio to begin with?

Comment: Because Im using it when im inserting everything in the db. How would I do that with just styling?